# limit probability of the sum of rolls is exactly $N$

Tags: probability

Given $N$

roll $2$ dice, the sum of two dice is $X_1$.

repeat many times until $S_k=X_1+\cdots+X_k\ge N$

$P_N=\mathbb{P}(\exists k,S_{k-1}<N,S_k=N)$

how to calculate the limit probability of $P_N$?

There is a relationship when $N$ is large

$$P_N=\sum_{k=2}^{12}P(X=k)P_{N-k}$$

where $X$ is the sum of two dices.

I tried to calculate limit probability by let $N\to\infty$, only to get
$$p=\sum_{k=2}^{12} P(X=k)p$$
which is trival.